# object orientated javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've got this object player1 and i can't get the `scene.add(Obj);` line to work as it comes up with an error saying `Obj` does not exist:

```
function Player(x, y, z) {
 this.Speed = 0;
 this.AngleAcc = 0;
 this.Angle = 0;
 this.X=x;
 this.Y=y;
 this.Z=z;
 this.MaxSpeed = 100;

 var PlayerMateririal = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x00ff80, overdraw: 0.5 });
 this.Obj = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 90, 60), PlayerMateririal);
 scene.add(Obj);
 Obj.position.set(x, y, z);
}
```

thanks i'm using Three.js and want to set the `Obj` position in other locations hence why i'm setting it up as a property.

Comment: You left off `this` - should be `this.Obj.position.set(...)`

Comment: `Obj` is not a variable. You defined it as a property of `this`, then you should use `this.Obj` or simply try `var Obj = this.Obj = new THREE....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this keyword

```
scene.add(this.Obj);
```